# Scala convert Option[T] to String

Tags: scala

Does exist any native function in scala that does the equivalent this?

```
def strConvert[T](v: Option[T]): String = {
    if (v.isDefined)
      v.get.toString
    else
      ""
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For generic `T`, you can avoid the if with `map` -- `v.map(_.toString).getOrElse("")`

Comment: @JordanParmer OP didn't mention that T == String

Answer (score 6):

```
scala> Some(1).fold("")(_.toString)
res0: String = 1

scala> None.fold("")(_.toString)
res1: String = ""
```

Answer (score 2):

`Option` is a monad. In FP, when working with monads, you define what you want to happen if the monad contains a state (i.e. a value other than `None`). Otherwise, you move on.

```
val ostring: Option[String] = functionThatGetsOptionString()

ostring.map { s =>
   functionThatUsesString(s)
}
```

Within the `map` function, `s` will contain the raw string if the `Option` is `Some(String)` otherwise it won't execute the inner body if `Option` is `None`.